# Stuck on a problem in MIT OCW 6.0001 problem set

Tags: python

I am an absolute noob to python (and programming in general) and am working my way through learning python by the help of an MIT OCW course (6.0001). But there's a problem on one of the problem set that I'm currently stuck on:

> You have graduated from MIT and now have a great job! You move to the
> San Francisco Bay Area and decide that you want to start saving to buy
> a house. As housing prices are very high in the Bay Area, you realize
> you are going to have to save for several years before you can afford
> to make the down payment on a house. In Part A, we are going to
> determine how long it will take you to save enough money to make the
> down payment given the following assumptions:
>
> 1. Call the cost of your dream home ​total_cost​.
> 2. Call the portion of the cost needed for a down payment ​portion_down_payment​. For simplicity, assume that
>    portion_down_payment = 0.25 (25%).
> 3. Call the amount that you have saved thus far ​current_savings​. You start with a current savings of $0.
> 4. Assume that you invest your current savings wisely, with an annual return of ​r ​(in other words, at the end of each month, you receive
>    an additional ​current_savings*r/12​ funds to put into your savings –
>    the 12 is because ​r​ is an annual rate). Assume that your investments
>    earn a return of r = 0.04 (4%).
> 5. Assume your annual salary is ​annual_salary​.
> 6. Assume you are going to dedicate a certain amount of your salary each month to saving for the down payment. Call that ​portion_saved​.
>    This variable should be in decimal form (i.e. 0.1 for 10%).
> 7. At the end of each month, your savings will be increased by the return on your investment, plus a percentage of your ​monthly salary
>    ​(annual salary / 12). Write a program to calculate how many months it
>    will take you to save up enough money for a down payment. You will
>    want your main variables to be floats, so you should cast user inputs
>    to floats. Your program should ask the user to enter the following
>    variables:
> 8. The starting annual salary (annual_salary)
> 9. The portion of salary to be saved (portion_saved)
> 10. The cost of your dream home (total_cost)

The program that I've written for the above is:

```
annual_salary = float(input("Your starting annual salary: $"))
portion_saved = float(input("The portion of salary to be saved: "))
total_cost = float(input("The cost of your dream home: $"))
##Initial values
portion_down_payment = 0.25*total_cost
current_savings = 0
r = 0.04
num_months = 1
#(assuming that salary for a given month is received at the end of the month)
##The program
monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
investment_earnings = current_savings*r/12
while ((monthly_salary*portion_saved)+investment_earnings+current_savings) <= portion_down_payment:
    current_savings = current_savings + (monthly_salary*portion_saved)
    investment_earnings = current_savings*r/12
    current_savings = current_savings + investment_earnings
    num_months = num_months + 1
else:
    print("Number of months:",num_months)
```

The problem that I'm facing with the above code is that though I'm getting a correct answer on one of the test cases, on the other case the number of months that I get is one less that what I should get as per the problem set.

Tested input:

```
Enter your annual salary:​ 120000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:​ .10
Enter the cost of your dream home:​ 1000000
```

Expected output:

```
Number of months:​ 183
```

Actual output:

```
Number of months:​ 182
```

Comment: Please post input, actual output and expected output (input as you feed it to the program, and output as you get it from it, both surely not as text !)

Comment: Hi @Programmer, I've added the input and (the actual and expected) output to the question.

Comment: Thanks, and next time do it please _before_ you post your question !

Comment: Can you please add input / expcted  + actual output for multiple test cases ? With one, I can't find the error …

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Just a side note, the `else` has no meaning there. It only plays a part if there is a `break` inside the loop...

Comment: Hi @Programmer thanks for trying to help me out. But going through my code again, I did figure out myself what the error was. I just needed to omit investment_earnings that's there in the while loop, as it's already included in the current_savings. Now it's showing up the correct output.

Comment: Glad to hear it works now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
annual_salary = float(input('Enter your annual salary:​ ')) 
portion_saved = float(input('Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: ​'))
total_cost = float(input('Enter the cost of your dream home: ​')) 

# initial values
current_savings = 0  #the amount that you have saved so far,starting from 0
portion_down_payment = 0.25 * total_cost
current_savings = 0  #the amount that you have saved so far,starting from 0
r = 0.04 #annual rate
annual_return = (current_savings * r) / 12
monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12
portion_saved = portion_saved * monthly_salary 
num_months = 0

#Iterations and Output
while (current_savings <= portion_down_payment):
    num_months += 1
    current_savings += (current_savings * r / 12) + portion_saved    
print('Number of months: %d'%num_months)
```